# Laravel get last row for each items

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-5

I use Laravel Eloquent and I have this table:

```
id  client_id  project_id  status_id
1       1          1         1
2       2          1         1
3       1          1         2
4       2          1         2
```

I want take the last row which insert for each client. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel offers method 'first' to take the very first matching record, how about first you order by descending and take the first row?

$affectedRow = TableName::where(condition)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

Comment: i find solution $lastRow = TableName::where(condition)->distinct('client_id')->get()     and after that i use for each  loop with $lastRow index